# Data sharing between multiple ViewModels

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light

Further to my question [how can I bind Bing Pushpins from multiple models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305582/how-can-i-bind-bing-pushpins-from-multiple-models)

This is pretty new to me and I have been searching through the web but there seem so many different approaches to MVVM and then adding in WP7 and I have got a bit confused

I am now trying to work out the best way to share data between ViewModels or even if that is the best way to do it.

What I mean is I have, for example

My models: PeopleModel, BuildingModel
My ViewModels: PeopleViewModel, BuildingViewModel (which contain Observable collections of the model)

At the moment a Timer is used to update the lists from a Webservice. The ViewModel because it is static is able to be updated during the lifetime of the application. I am not sure this is the most sensible approach though but I need some form of background sync to fit the requirements.

The People and Building contain a location but not anything regarding what image it should display as a pushpin. So I was thinking if I had a my map view containing a MapViewModel that is linked somehow to the ViewModels but I am not sure how you would do this.

I looked at MVVMLight and it seems you can register the ViewModels at start so it would be possible to add links to the other ViewModels and not worry about the lifetimes of them?

However given that there is extra information within the Models that the Map isn't interested in I wonder if is better to have a self-contained MapViewModel that contains lists of Custom pushpins of some type (so PeoplePushpins, BuildingPushpins). If I go this route I would like to know how you update the MapViewModel from data updated in the other Models.

What I mean is the running timer in PersonViewModel detects a change in the list, so updates its own list. I the need to send notification to the Map that there is an update which then will update itself from that.

Any help/advice gratefully received.

Comment: Can you please not preface your question title with a tag?  You've already got the WP7 tag on your question.  Tags work pretty dang well here; placing redundant tags in the title won't help you get your question answered.  Can you pretty please not do it?  For me?

Comment: Okay didn't realise. Thanks for advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MVVMLight you can use messaging to send data between models:

```
//build class to send as message  
public class AddPushPinMessage
{
    public PushPin PushPin { get; set; }
}

public class ReceivingViewModel
{
  public ReceivingViewModel()
  {
     Messenger.Default.Register<AddPushPinMessage>(this, (m) => AddPushPin(m));
  }

  void AddPushPin(AddPushPinMessage msg)
  {
     //handle message
  }
}

public class SendingViewModel
{
  private object SendPushPin(PushPin key)
  { 
    Messenger.Default.Send<AddPushPinMessage>(new SetPushPinMessage() { PushPin = key });

    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks very much like what I was looking for. I had read about messaging but an example like this is always useful. Finding that raising property changes was also possible to send objects with their old and current values such as `RaisePropertyChanged("StringOne", oldValue, value, true);` may also prove to be useful to me. Hopefully sending data this way isn't too intensive

Comment: i think you should not overdo the publish and subscribing, i have never had any performance issues with it but i try to keep it low especially on a windows phone app. when you are using this messaging, be sure you create the viewmodels at the right time, otherwise your messages won't arrive.

Comment: The aim is that I work out what is possible in WP7 trying to follow best practices. If a process doesn't work properly then I can look into alternatives. Thanks for the advice.